# Aysnc forEachOf cannot read property

Tags: javascript, node.js

Could someone tell me why I have error like this:

When self.player are empty and I add new item, then all is okay, when someone other add second item to array, then next I want to add third item, then return error like below.

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'profile' of undefined
>       at async.forEachOf.self.players.push.profile (/home/backend/index.js:1976:29)

My code look like:

```
console.log(self.players);
            async.forEachOf(self.players, function(value, key, callback) {
                if(value.profile.steamid.toString() == player.steamid.toString()){
                    itemsHashMarket.push(value.items[0]);    
                    //amount = parseInt(amount) + parseInt(value.bet);
                    self.players.splice(key, 1);
                }
                callback();
             }, function() {

                self.players.push({ profile: player, bet: amount, items: itemsHashMarket, percent: self._playerPercent, total: self._cash}); 


                return callback(null, {timeleft: self._timeLeft, players: [{ profile: player, bet: amount, items: itemsHashMarket, percent: self._playerPercent, total: self._cash}], hash: self._hash, percent: self._playerPercent, cash: self._cash, countitems:self._countItems}); // Broadcast newPlayer
            });
```

self.player with 2 elements:
[image]

Comment: I think that your problem is `self.players.splice(key, 1);`. It's not good idea to change array during iteration.

Comment: yes You have right :)